# React router not rendered with second click

Tags: reactjs

I use Router like the code below to switch between components includes Home, Sidebar, Detail, Category.

For the first load, It will display all recent posts, featured posts. 
When I click a post to go detail It work well.
In detail page, I click to render new post but It does not render.

My code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        // if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        //     const registration = runtime.register();
        // }
        module.hot.accept(); 
        $("body").removeClass();
        $("body").addClass("homepage");
        <Helmet>
            <title>{blog_title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={blog_description} />
        </Helmet>
        const {feature, main, sidebar, mainbottom, header } = this.props;
        return (
            <div id="all">
                {header}
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="main-feature" id="main-feature">
                        {feature}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="content" className="site-content">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="divcontainer">
                            <div id="po-homepage" className="content-area">
                                {main}
                            </div>
                            <aside id="secondary" className="sidebar widget-area">
                                <div className="popular_post" id="popular_post">
                                    {sidebar}
                                </div>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="cat-list">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="thecategories" id="thecategories">
                            {mainbottom}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Please see photo:

[image]

My detail post:

```js
import React, {Component} from "react"; //nếu chỉ import React thì sẽ cần React.Component
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

class Detail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    //scroll to detail
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top - 100 }, 500);
      $("body").removeClass();
      $("body").addClass("detailpage");
    }); 

    console.log(this.props.detailink); 

    var that = this; 
    var url = window.location.href.split("/");
    var slug = url.pop() || url.pop();
   // console.log(CelestialSettings.URL.api + "/posts?slug=" + slug);
    fetch(CelestialSettings.URL.api + "/posts?slug=" + slug)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();  
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        that.setState({ post: res[0] });
      });
  }

  renderPosts() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <Helmet>
            <title>{this.state.post.title.rendered}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={this.state.post.excerpt.rendered.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")} />
          </Helmet>
          <h1 className="card-title">{this.state.post.title.rendered}</h1>
          <p className="card-text">
            <small className="text-muted">
              {this.state.post.author_name} &ndash;{" "}  
              {this.state.post.published_date}
            </small>
          </p>
          {this.state.post.featured_image_src ? (
            <img
              className="featured-image"
              src={this.state.post.featured_image_src}
              alt="featured image"
            />
          ) : null}
          <p
            className="card-text"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: this.state.post.content.rendered
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderEmpty() {
    return (
     <div></div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    var href = window.location.href+"/?view=react"; 
    return (
      <div className="container post-entry">
        {this.state.post.title ? this.renderPosts() : this.renderEmpty()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Detail;
```

As I added ComponentDidUpdate(), it works but it renders loop back top first detail before render new post. I use like this.

```
componentDidUpdate() {

    var that = this; 
    var url = window.location.href.split("/");
    var slug = url.pop() || url.pop();
   console.log(CelestialSettings.URL.api + "/posts?slug=" + slug);
    fetch(CelestialSettings.URL.api + "/posts?slug=" + slug)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();  
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        that.setState({ post: res[0] });
      });
  }
```

Any suggestion for my issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: is your `<Detail>` component exported with `withRouter`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I do not know it. Can you explain me?

Comment: Please show the code with your `Detail` component.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thank you so much. I updated detail component

Comment: Added answer with a solution.

Comment: Well, you only fetch the post when your component mounted, but not when your component receives updates, as long as it doesn't unmount, it will just show what you initially loaded (with `componentDidMount`), how does your router look? Maybe you can send the details for the menu through props instead

Comment: Hi @Icepickle can you give me an answer?

Comment: Hai Tien, Both @GabrielePetrioli and me gave you an idea what you can change (through, both in comments, but you have something to look at :) ). You just have to detect that certain changes are made, and load the matching posts

Comment: @Icepickle I am sorry. Actually, I have no idea about ComponentDidUpdate. Can you check my updated question?

Comment: Is the problem that you now continuously go into `ComponentDidUpdate`? I don't understand your `loop` reference. You could simply check if your `slug` is the same or not (I might rather go for `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate`) to arrange the change (as you could compare state/props there)

Comment: Hi @Icepickle. It is infinite loop. I do not know how to compare previous data with new render data. Can you add to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Detail` component needs to be aware that the url changed and since no relevant properties are passed when you try to render it you must use the [`withRouter` HOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) provided by react router

so at the top of your Details component file

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  withRouter // add this (and the comma in the above line)
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and at the bottom where you `export` it use

```js
export default withRouter(Detail);
```

---

**Update**

Reading your `Details` code a bit more i see that you `fetch` the content on the `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle event, but when you load a new post you remain to the same page so the `Details` component is not unmounted/remounted, it is just updated with new props and so the `ComponentDidMount` does not fire again. You will have to also use [`ComponentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Some additional info

1. Since you are using the react-router you should not be parsing the `window.location.href` yourself trying to figure the slug. You can automatically pass it down from the props provided by the router.

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-js -->

   <Route
     path={CelestialSettings.path + 'posts/:slug'} 
     render={(props) => <App header={<Header/>} 
                         main={<Detail slug={props.match.slug} detailink={CelestialSettings.path + 'posts/:slug'} />} 
                         sidebar={<Popular />} 
                         feature={<Featurex/>} 
                         mainbottom={<Categories/>} />} />
   ```
2. Then in your `ComponentDidUpdate`

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-js -->

   componentDidUpdate(newProps) {
     const {slug} = newProps;
     const that = this; // you do not need this if you use arrow functions

     if (slug !== this.props.slug) {
       fetch(CelestialSettings.URL.api + "/posts?slug=" + slug)
         .then(function(response) {
           if (!response.ok) {
             throw Error(response.statusText);
           }
           return response.json();
         })
         .then(function(res) {
           that.setState({
             post: res[0]
           });
         });
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much but it seems that it does not work. Do you know reason why?

Comment: @HaiTien i see. Reading your `Details` code a bit more i see that you fetch the content on the `ComponentDidMount`, but when you change load a new post you remain to the same page so the `Details` component is not unmounted/remounted, it is just updated with new props so the `ComponentDidMount` does not fire again. You will have to also use [`ComponentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Wouldn't that be info that should be part of the answer instead of as a comment? :)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thank you so much. I am trying

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you so much. I am understanding your answer but as you compare slug. It returns nothing. I added else  of  `if (slug !== this.props.slug)` and it goes to this. Can you check again?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli and this.props.slug returns undefined. I do not know why

Comment: @HaiTien i had a typo in the code `slug={pros.match.slug}` should be `slug={props.match.slug}`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you so much for your assistance but I made change it before you corrected but still not working.

Comment: @HaiTien do you have the project on github or can you recreate it in something like codesandbox.io so i can see it in action?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you so much but this is my client project. I found solution using match.